# iOS WebKit crash

Tags: ios, swift, webkit, wkwebview

[image: WebKit Crash Log]

In my app, I'm receiving thousands of crashes from this log. It's very mysterious and impossible for me to reproduce. There is not a single trace of the app process leading up to the crash in the backtrace, furthering my confusion. My app contains a WKWebView if that helps.

I would appreciate any help trying to diagnose the root cause of these crashes and a possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering this myself. This UIImageView that's crashing is actually the vertical scroll indicator within the WKScrollView. It took me a long time to find this.

I found a workaround. If you hide these indicators, it will not crash.